# How to combine two conditions in a where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following:

```
time_range = (1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)

Comment.where(:created_at => time_range).count
```

How can I add to the where clause with a statement like:

```
.where("user_id is not in (?)",[user_ids]).
```

How can I combine the two? Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

#### solution 1: ( I prefer , more easy to understand)

Just write it like raw SQL:

```
Comment.where(
   "(user_id > ? AND user_id < ? ) OR (created_at > ? AND created_at < ?)",
   100, 200, "2022-06-01", "2022-06-05")
```

#### solution 2:

```
Comment.
  where(:created_at => time_range).
  where("user_id is not in (?)",[user_ids])
```

which will produce SQL like :  `select ... where ... AND ...`

Comment: That errors w ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "in"

Answer (score 23):

```
User.where(["name = ? and email = ?", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])
```

This will be fine.

Answer (score 23):

```
User.where(name: 'Joe', email: 'joe@example.com')
```