# Query on ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do you query on Ruby on Rails or translate this query on Ruby on Rails?

```
SELECT
orders.item_total,
orders.total,
payments.created_at,
payments.updated_at
FROM
public.payments,
public.orders,
public.line_items,
public.variants
WHERE
payments.order_id = orders.id AND
orders.id = line_items.order_id AND
```

This is working on Postgres but I'm new to RoR and it's giving me difficulty on querying this sample.

So far this is what I have.

```
Order.joins(:payments,:line_items,:variants).where(payments:{order_id: [Order.ids]}, orders:{id:LineItem.orders_id}).distinct.pluck(:email, :id, "payments.created_at", "payments.updated_at")
```

I have a lot of reference before asking a question here are the links.

[How to combine two conditions in a where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611795/how-to-combine-two-conditions-in-a-where-clause)

[Rails PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106853/rails-pgundefinedtable-error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table/27107299)

[Rails ActiveRecord: Pluck from multiple tables with same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306820/rails-activerecord-pluck-from-multiple-tables-with-same-column-name/33307036)

[ActiveRecord find and only return selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911014/activerecord-find-and-only-return-selected-columns)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_querying.html

from all that link I produced this code that works for testing.

`Spree::Order.joins(:payments,:line_items,:variants).where(id: [Spree::Payment.ids]).distinct.pluck(:email, :id)`

but when I try to have multiple queries and pluck a specific column name from a different table it gives me an error.

### Update

So I'm using Ransack to query I produced this code.

```
 @search = Spree::Order.ransack(
          orders_gt: params[:q][:created_at_gt],
          orders_lt: params[:q][:created_at_lt],
          payments_order_id_in: [Spree::Order.ids],
          payments_state_eq: 'completed',
          orders_id_in: [Spree::LineItem.all.pluck(:order_id)],
          variants_id_in: [Spree::LineItem.ids]
        )

        @payment_report = @search.result
                                        .includes(:payments, :line_items, :variants)
                                        .joins(:line_items, :payments, :variants).select('payments.response_code, orders.number, payments.number')
```

I don't have error when I remove the select part and I need to get that specific column. Is there a way?

Comment: Gives you what error?

Comment: Something is wrong here ` orders:{id:LineItem.orders_id})` order_ids maybe?

Comment: I get an Error missing FROM-Clause...

Comment: You must use the `spree_` suffix in your tables. `spree_payments`, `spree_orders` and so on

Comment: @GonzaloMorenoCaballero yea I just figured it out. but other data are still missing like `spree_payments.response_code` and 2 others.

Comment: @GonzaloMorenoCaballero but when I pluck them one by one its giving me the values i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make a join between the tables and then select the columns you want

```
Spree::Order.joins(:payments, :line_items).pluck("spree_orders.total, spree_orders.item_total, spree_payments.created_at, spree_payments.updated_at")
```

or

```
Spree::Order.joins(:payments, :line_items).select("spree_orders.total, spree_orders.item_total, spree_payments.created_at, spree_payments.updated_at")
```

That is equivalent to this query

```
SELECT spree_orders.total,
spree_orders.item_total, 
spree_payments.created_at, 
spree_payments.updated_at 
FROM "spree_orders" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_payments" ON "spree_payments"."order_id" = "spree_orders"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_line_items" ON "spree_line_items"."order_id" = "spree_orders"."id"
```

Comment: Thank for this but dude why mine is not working? I updated my question

Answer (score -1):

You can use `select_all` method.This method will return an instance of `ActiveRecord::Result` class and calling `to_hash` on this object would return you an array of hashes where each hash indicates a record.

```
Order.connection.select_all("SELECT
orders.item_total,
orders.total,
payments.created_at,
payments.updated_at
FROM
public.payments,
public.orders,
public.line_items,
public.variants
WHERE
payments.order_id = orders.id AND
orders.id = line_items.order_id").to_hash
```